# Best practices for the cache of a static WordPress site, including CDN Cache and Cache Plugin

Tags: cache, cdn

I am studying the best practices for the cache for a Wordpress site. THe Wordpress site is:

Not updated frequently(maybe once in a week).
The update is only initiated and controlled from me, it does not contain updates from external sources, such as comments.
In such a case, I just wonder what is the best practices for the cache, including:

The cache plugin(Currently I am using WP Rocket).
The cache in the CDN.
Currently my plan is to:

Set all TTL(including browser TTL, edge TTL, client TTL, etc.) for both 1) and 2) to as long as possible, for example, 1 year or 10 years. I get this idea from the article at https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/18-using-wp-rocket-with-cloudflare#optimal-settings, which said its optimal setting will set the Cloudflare browser cache TTL to 1 year.
When I update or delete a page, I will purge the corresponding page in both 1) and 2)
When I add a new page, nothing need to be done.
The only issue is the client TTL or browser TTL, I can purge the cached page in the CDN cache and cache plugin, but cannot purge that in the client computer(browser), so should I set a lower value for the client TTL or browser TTL?

Comment: There isn't necessary a best practice. The TTL depends on your site's content and functionality. For example, does your site have a recent posts list in the sidebar? If so, your TTL on page caches will need to be low enough that this is kept up to date, and that will depend on how frequently you post. There's too many variables to give a universal answer.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, For your case, if the site is not updated frequently, for example, update once per month. How about set the TTL to one month and purge all pages when I update it?

Comment: You would need to ask the plugin developer how to set specific settings for that plugin.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, Thank you very much. Actuall Browse TTL is set by the plugin and edge TTL is set by the CDN provider, the plugin and the CDN provider have documents that are sometimes contradict to each other, so I want to find whether there is a best practice on this.